# how to automatically import multiple csv files into Google Sheets using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a lot of CSV files and I want to download them all in one google sheet. I found this script but it didn't work for me. What is the problem?

You put everything right and when you execute the command it says everything is okay without errors
Please help me with this and thanks

```js
function importCSVFiles()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const csvFolderName = 'Mean Histogram';  // Name Folder containing csv files and the Archive folder
  const rootFolderId = '1nffVYwaHVv9DqEPdAvGT7a5gJvH4pHlx';  // Id Root csv folder
  const archiveFolderId = '1k4gFlU021pvY54bSMSRo2XdGFmAKHeWi';  // Id Archive Folder
  const destinationSheetName = 'Mean_Histogram'; // Name destination sheet in spreadsheet
  
  const root = DriveApp.getFolderById(rootFolderId);
  const archiveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(archiveFolderId);
  const fileName =/ *.csv/;
  
  
  var rootFolders = root.getFolders();

  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  var csvArray = [];
  
  while (rootFolders.hasNext()) 
  {
    var folder = rootFolders.next ();
    Logger.log('folder.getName()',folder.getName());
    if (folder.getName() === csvFolderName) 
    {
      importCSV(folder);
    }
    else 
    {
      var csvFolder = folder.getFoldersByName(csvFolderName);
      while (csvFolder.hasNext()) 
      {
        importCSV(csvFolder.next());
      }
    }
  }
  
  function importCSV(folder) 
  {
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) 
    {
      var file = files.next();
      if (file.getName (). match (fileName)) 
      {
        Logger.log('file.getName()',file.getName());
      csvArray = file.getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-8");
      csvArray = Utilities.parseCsv(csvArray);
      csvArray.shift();
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(1,csvArray.length);
      sheet.getRange (2,1,csvArray.length,csvArray[0].length).setValues(csvArray);
      
      file.moveTo(archiveFolder);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Yassin, 
I think it would be a better option to write your own code and understand everything step by step. Don't worry, I can help you with that, but I would need an extensive explanation about your context. Do you have several csv files in one or in several folders? Do you want to import each csv file in a different sheet or all of them in the same sheet? How do they look like? With all this information I can give you a solution.

Comment: Oh thank you ..@fullfine
Yes, I have several csv files in one folder and I want to import all csv files, meaning all of them in one sheet. Nothing .. However, I found this code and did everything and it did not work ..

Answer (score 1):

I write a piece of code to handle your needs. I have included a functionality to skip the headers of the recurrent files after the first one is taken. You only have to specify the name of the folder where the csv files are and if you want to skip the headers.

```
function importCsvFiles(folderName, skipHeader) {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next()
  const files = folder.getFiles()
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  let headerWritten = false

  while (files.hasNext()){
    const file = files.next()
    const data = file.getBlob().getDataAsString()
    const csv = Utilities.parseCsv(data, ';')
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    
    // skip headers
    if (skipHeader && headerWritten) {
      csv.splice(0,1)
    } else if (skipHeader && headerWritten == false) {
      headerWritten = true
    }
    
    sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv)
  }
}

function main(){
  var name_folder = 'CSV FILES'
  var skip_header = true
  importCsvFiles(name_folder, skip_header)
}
```

Comment: He @fullfine writes one column, writes a new column, and records each column according to the data in the C file,
Can you correct the script first that does not work

Comment: Hi Yassin. I would ask you to give a more detailed explanation of your problem so that I can fully understand it. What exactly are you getting and what do you expect? What do you mean with "writes one column, writes and new column.."? Which is the C file? Besides, the script you posted searches in different folders when in your case only one folder is needed, I don't understand the advantage of using it before mine. Finally, something that can make your result not be the desired one is the line "Utilities.parseCsv(data, ';')". Maybe the delimiter of your csv files is different.

Comment: Thank you very much @fullfine for standing by and helping me. I am very grateful to you.
According to the problem, the code is your own, that it writes the data in one column and I want to write all the data separated by a " [ , ]" in a column and the code does not do that..

Comment: Have you checked that the delimiter of your csv files is `;`? Depending on the format of your files, you will have to specify one delimiter or another. In my code I wrote `;` because I had this type of files. Also, I'm still not sure I understand your problem, could you add some images in the description of what you get and what you expect? My code writes each item in a row to a different column, isn't that what you want? Or do you want to write each csv in a column with their values separated by `,`?